# How do I setup a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B to do a network install via TFTP?

Tags: networking, software-installation, bootloader, u-boot, tftp

I have a TFTP server, and I want to install any new Raspberry Pis on my network to use the TFTP server to install the OS. How do I got about doing this, I checked the Documentation on the official website and I can't find the documentation.

Also how can I do this so I can reimage an existing raspberry pi if I don't have physical access to it.

Comment: Interested to see if this is possible :)

Comment: If not is it possible to remotely reimage an operating system, if you don't have physical access to. Assuming you have SSH.

Comment: There *might* be a sneaky way to reimage the card if you run the OS from external storage.   WRT installing an OS that way, obviously you have to have an OS running, so either you do the same thing (run from a USB stick, etc) or else you have a look at how NOOBs or [BerryBoot](http://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/berryboot) works.  Either way, there's not going to be a simple recipe to follow for this.

Comment: Since in all cases you would have to have an OS installed and running on the pi first, you might want to stop and consider [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/212479) -- if you just want to configure/update the system and backup/restore it online, there are better options than having to burn a whole card or partition image.

Comment: How about [TFTP boot](http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot#Network_boot_via_TFTP) instead? I can turn this into a fully fledged answer, if it meets your needs.

Comment: @Greenonline I would find an answer about using u-boot to automatically boot a raspbian kernel using tftp very useful. Specifically, I'm stuck on the boot.scr.uimg bootargs and the files that need to be served. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Only the Raspberry Pi 3** can boot from network without special software on an *inserted SD Card* (you need to use U-Boot or a sepcial bootcode.bin on older models).

**The instructions for the Pi 3 are [here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes).**
Since you have a Pi2 , an alternative approach is to use a rootfs over NFS , as demonstrated by [PiNet](http://pinet.org.uk/).

BerryBoot (Linux only) supports booting via [iSCSI](https://www.berryterminal.com/doku.php/storing_your_files_on_a_synology_nas_using_iscsi) or from Samba/Windows Shares.

Because the nature of the Pis booting process , you still cannot skip the official second-stage start.elf bootloader (which now gets delivered over network).